# How can I get the img displaying full length in mobile?

Tags: css

Currently trying to display my img full length, when the browser(chrome latest) width is  400px there is some space under the img:

When I make the browserwidth 470px there is no issue. How can I fix this for the mobile view for 400px?

This is the relevant fragment:

```
<div class="visible-xs">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 employee">
                    <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bertboerland/128.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                      <div><span class="name"> Isabelle &nbsp;Clarke</span></div>
                      <div>International Group Engineer</div>
                      <div>39</div>
                      <div>10/07/2016</div>
                      <div>Vel velit repellat dicta. Maxime occaecati sed dolorum et modi. Voluptates rerum</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will make the image full height but stretched. You can add flex display and use height:100% like this :

```
@media all and (max-width:470px) {
  .employee {
      display:flex;
  }
  .employee img {
     height:100%;
  }
}
```